# Устранение кнопок (и других компонентов swing)

Tags: java, swing

Пытаюсь написать "Игру в Жизнь". У меня имеется класс `cell`, в котором кнопка (отображающая клетку и её состояние), `boolean`-состояние клетки и её координаты. С помощью метода создаётся "игровое поле" `cell[N][M]`, где N и M задаются пользователем.

Проблема: создание поля, которое по размерам больше имеющегося проходит нормально, но вот создать поле размерами меньше не получается. Старые кнопки остаются. Просто приравнять `cell[][] = null` и `repaint()` не дают нужного результата.

Вопрос: как избавиться от созданных кнопок. Желательно не просто скрыть `setVisible(false)`, а именно убрать окончательно, чтобы они не забивали память?

Вот код метода, который создаёт поле:

```
if(tfSizeX.getText().length() > 0 && tfSizeY.getText().length() > 0 
             && tfCellSize.getText().length() > 0)
{
    grid = null; // Cell[][] grid;
    int sizeGridX = Integer.parseInt(tfSizeX.getText());
    int sizeGridY = Integer.parseInt(tfSizeY.getText());
    int sizeCell = Integer.parseInt(tfCellSize.getText());
    grid = new Cell[sizeGridX][sizeGridY];
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeGridX; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < sizeGridY; j++)
            grid[i][j] = new Cell(i*(sizeCell+1), j*(sizeCell+1), panel, sizeCell);
    panel.repaint();
}
```

А вот класс `Cell`:

```
public class Cell 
{
    private JButton cell;
    private boolean condition;
    int locX, locY, size = 24;

    public Cell(int locX, int locY, JPanel panel, int size)
    {
        this.size = size;

        condition = false;
        cell = new JButton("");
        cell.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                if(!condition)
                {
                    cell.setBackground(Color.black);
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.setBackground(Color.white);
                }
                condition = !condition;
            }
        });
        cell.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        cell.setBounds(locX, locY, size, size); 
        panel.add(cell);
        cell.setBackground(Color.white);
    }

    public void change(boolean condition)
    {
        this.condition = condition;
        if(condition)
        {
            cell.setBackground(Color.black);
        }
        else
        {
            cell.setBackground(Color.white);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы используете `panel.add()`. Я подозреваю, что должен существовать и метод `panel.remove()`, благодаря которому можно убрать старые клетки из панели (и, соответственно, из отрисовки).

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете удалить отдельные клетки с помощью `panel.remove(cell)`. Либо удалить все дочерние компоненты через `panel.removeAll()`, а затем всё добавить заново.